# Efficiently implementing Matlab's "Find" function in Julia

Tags: matlab, search, optimization, find, julia

I'm trying to implement Matlab's Find function in Julia. In Matlab, the code is

```
find(A==0)
```

where A is a very, very large n by m matrix, and where I iterate and update the above over a series of about 500 steps. In Julia, I implement the above via

```
[findall(x->x==0, D_tot)[j][2] for j in 1:count(x->x==0,D_tot)]
```

This seems to work nicely, except it goes very slow as I progress with my iteration. For example, for the first step, @time yields

```
0.000432 seconds (33 allocations: 3.141 KiB)
```

Step 25:

```
0.546958 seconds (40.37 k allocations: 389.997 MiB, 7.40% gc time)
```

Step 65:

```
1.765892 seconds (86.73 k allocations: 1.516 GiB, 9.63% gc time)
```

At each step, A remains the same size but becomes more complex, and Julia seems to have trouble finding the zeroes. Is there a better way of implementing Matlab's "Find" function than what I did above?

Comment: Just write `findall(iszero, A)`. Why are you doing all these other steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going through the Matlab documentation I understand that you want to find

> "a vector containing the linear indices of each nonzero element in array X"

and by non-zero you meant true values in Matlab's expression `A==0`

In that case this can be accomplished as

```
findall(==(0),vec(D_tot))
```

And a small benchmark:

```
D_tot=rand(0:100,1000,1000)
using BenchmarkTools
```

Running:

```
julia> @btime findall(==(0), vec($D_tot));
  615.100 μs (17 allocations: 256.80 KiB)

julia> @btime findall(iszero, vec($D_tot));
  665.799 μs (17 allocations: 256.80 KiB)
```

Comment: That timing is very strange. What's going on with `iszero`? Have you tried several times?

Comment: yes several times and it is strange indeed. I run `@code_native` and there are tiny differences in the assembly code (even the number of assembly instructions differs by 3) - so this seems not to be random.